# При наведении всплывающие окна рядом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть идентичные элементы на странице. При наведении на любой из них должно появляться всплывающее окно рядом. Но проблема в том, что при наведении всплывают окна сразу рядом со всеми, при чем при наведении на некоторые вообще ничего не происходит. Как с этим быть, подскажите пожалуйста.(присвоить каждому id не годится).

```js
$(function() {
 $('#info').hover(
  function($this){
   $('.modalInfo').toggleClass('active');}
   );
      });
```

```css
.modalInfo {
  display: none;
}
.info {
  display: block
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.modalInfo.active {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class = "info" id="info">INFO</i>

<div class = "modalInfo">
<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает</p>
</div>

<i class = "info" id="info">INFO</i>

<div class = "modalInfo">
<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает</p>
</div>

<i class = "info" id="info">INFO</i>

<div class = "modalInfo">
<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает</p>
</div>

<i class = "info" id="info">INFO</i>

<div class = "modalInfo">
<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Вас не смущает что у нескольких элементов одинаковый id?

Comment: Так их может быть хоть тысяча , я ж не буду каждому отдельный id присваивать. Может я что-то не так понимаю...

Comment: Явно не понимаете. Как интерпретатор языка должен понять на какой блок вы наводите мышь, если у них одинаковый ид? Зачем несколько блоков modalInfo с одинаковым содержанием?

Comment: для связывания группы элементов используются *классы*, а не *id*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых на одной страницы неправильно располагать несколько элементов с одинаковыми `id`. Во-вторых, почему бы не вынести HTML разметку в `data` для удобства и чтобы не плодить кучу "модальных окон"?

По решению: есть один элемент с `id=modal` - это модальное окно. При наведении на `.info` сетаем ему позицию `top` и `left` относительно элемента, на который мы навели мышь. Получаем данные из аттрибута `data-modal-text`, создаем `#modal` и вставляем в него данные. При выходе мыши с элемента - удаляем `#modal`.

```js
$('.info').hover(
  function() {
    let top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    let left = $(this).offset().left;
    let data = $(this).data('modal-text');

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'modal';
    $(div).css('top', top);
    $(div).css('left', left);
    $(div).html(data);
    $('body').append(div);
  },
  function() {
    $('#modal').remove();
  });
```

```css
.info {
  display: block width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#modal {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="info" data-modal-text="<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-text="<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-text="<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-text="<p>Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>">INFO</i>
```

Либо, если HTML в этих "модальных окнах" может быть большим, то будет красивее представить их в виде разметки и провайдить `data-modal-id`:

```js
$('.info').hover(
  function() {
    let top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    let left = $(this).offset().left;
    let modalId = '#' + $(this).data('modal-id');
    let data = $(modalId).html();

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'modal';
    $(div).css('top', top);
    $(div).css('left', left);
    $(div).html(data);
    $('body').append(div);
  },
  function() {
    $('#modal').remove();
  });
```

```css
.info {
  display: block width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#modal {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
}

.modal-data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="info" data-modal-id="info1data">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-id="info2data">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-id="info3data">INFO</i>

<i class="info" data-modal-id="info4data">INFO</i>

<div id="info1data" class="modal-data">
  <p>info1data: Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>
</div>

<div id="info2data" class="modal-data">
  <p>info2data: Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>
</div>

<div id="info3data" class="modal-data">
  <p>info3data: Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>
</div>

<div id="info4data" class="modal-data">
  <p>info4data: Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый. текст мешает</p>
</div>
```

Почитать:

- [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/)
- [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: `Во-первых на одной страницы не может находится несколько элементов с одинаковыми id` - на самом деле может.......это не совсем правильно определение, кмк.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский действительно, спасибо, обновил :)